# CSS Div Min-Height not fit until bottom page

Tags: html, css

I'm facing problem with my div min-height.

When I try to full screen the browser, the border of div isn't fit until bottom.
Here is the CSS :

```
body_wall
{
width: 878px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
left: 0;
right: 0;
position: absolute;
border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;
border-right: 1px solid #dddddd;
padding: 10px;
min-height: 800px;
height: auto !important;
}
```

The demo in fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DW3UG/2/show/)

Try to full screen that.

Any advice ? Please help.

Comment: i dont completely understand your problem, specifically 'not fit until bottom page' ...however your fiddle in full screen has left and right borders until bottom of page under debian 6 chrome 19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put a

```
  body{
       height :100%;
      }
```

for the body in your stylesheet. It tells the body element to strech to any available space after your minimum height.